# Delete data in /Android/data/packagename/cache

Tags: android

I want to use the Android data folder for my app and it worked fine. Now I have a question about the cache folder.

I read that Android or other 3rd party apps can delete all content in there, what should not be a problem for me. But what about temp files?

I had to download large ZIP files from the web. Can someone delete them while downloading or are they "read-only" for other processes?

Edit:

Cache folder: **Context.getExternalCacheDir()**

Current temp folder: **Context.getExternalFilesDir(null).getPath() + "/temp"**

Comment: Please start with showing how your app determines the data, cache and temp folders as an answer depends on the paths used.

Comment: I added the code into the original post.

Comment: All files in external dirs can be accessed by all other apps. No read or write protection.